# how can i use Description attribute work with swashbuckle

Tags: asp.net-core, swashbuckle

I am using the latest version of swashbuckle for .net core and I want swashbuckle to repspect the property Description so that for all parameters the description will be used for the swagger file

```
public class dtoClass
{
    [System.ComponentModel.Description("desciption swagger Name")]
    public string name {get; set; }
}
```

Is there an extention point/ filter in swashbuckle to be used?

my current soltion is to add the SwaggerSchema attribute.

```
public class dtoClass
{
    [System.ComponentModel.Description("desciption swagger Name")]
    [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations("desciption swagger Name")]
    public string name {get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use schema filter

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SchemaFilter<DescriptionSchemaFilter>();
});
```

Where `DescriptionSchemaFilter` is

```
internal class DescriptionSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.ParameterInfo != null)
        {
            var descriptionAttributes = context.ParameterInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

            if (descriptionAttributes.Length > 0)
            {
                var descriptionAttribute = (DescriptionAttribute)descriptionAttributes[0];
                schema.Description = descriptionAttribute.Description;
            }
        }

        if (context.MemberInfo != null)
        {
            var descriptionAttributes = context.MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

            if (descriptionAttributes.Length > 0)
            {
                var descriptionAttribute = (DescriptionAttribute)descriptionAttributes[0];
                schema.Description = descriptionAttribute.Description;
            }
        }

        if (context.Type != null)
        {
            var descriptionAttributes = context.Type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

            if (descriptionAttributes.Length > 0)
            {
                var descriptionAttribute = (DescriptionAttribute)descriptionAttributes[0];
                schema.Description = descriptionAttribute.Description;
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

And code:

[image]

in swagger look's like:

[image]